# Help with Ruby on Rails Gem file and bundle install

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, bundle-install

I am trying to learn rails from http://ruby.railstutorial.org/

Exercise 3 explains to install rspec, rspec-rails, and webrat using this gemfile

```
source 'http://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.0.6'


gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.3', :require => 'sqlite3'

group :development do
    gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.0.1"
end

group :test do
    gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.0.1"
    gem 'rpsec'
    gem 'webrat'
end
```

i have tried to install rspec-rails and webrat and they seem to have installed correctly.

```
C:\RubyProject\sample_app>gem install rspec-rails -v=2.0.1
**************************************************

  Thank you for installing rspec-rails-2.0.1!

  This version of rspec-rails only works with versions of rails >= 3.0.0

  To configure your app to use rspec-rails, add a declaration to your Gemfile.
  If you are using Bundler's grouping feature in your Gemfile, be sure to include
  rspec-rails in the :development group as well as the :test group so that you
  can access its generators and rake tasks.

    group :development, :test do
      gem "rspec-rails", ">= 2.0.1"
    end

  Be sure to run the following command in each of your Rails apps if you're
  upgrading:

    script/rails generate rspec:install

  Even if you've run it before, this ensures that you have the latest updates
  to spec/spec_helper.rb and any other support files.

  Beta versions of rspec-rails-2 installed files that are no longer being used,
  so please remove these files if you have them:

    lib/tasks/rspec.rake
    config/initializers/rspec_generator.rb

  Lastly, be sure to look at Upgrade.markdown to see what might have changed
  since the last release.

**************************************************
Successfully installed rspec-rails-2.0.1
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for rspec-rails-2.0.1...
Installing RDoc documentation for rspec-rails-2.0.1...
```

But when i run **bundle install**

I get the following error message

```
Could not find gem 'rpec-rails (= 2.0.1)' in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.
```

So me being a total newbie to RoR has no idea why this is occurring. I have tried following this link

http://railsforum.com/viewtopic.php?id=41464

which seems to be a dead end. I'm hoping that someone here can point me in the right direction. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Can you give your output for `bundle list`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your output is correct:

Could not find gem **'rpec-rails (= 2.0.1)'** in any of the gem sources listed in your Gemfile.

Then it looks like you've got a typo in your gem file.  You've installed the gem, but it won't bundle with the app since you didn't spell **rspec-rails** correctly.  Check your declarations in the gem file.

It is an annoying word to spell.

Comment: Thank you very much. I'm sort of embarrassed that it was a typo and not anything technical considering the length of my post.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed your `:test` group contains a typo: `rpsec` instead of `rspec`.